# What de-icing products can be used on a patterned concrete walkway / driveway? (Salt causes problems.)

Tags: safety, driveway, winter, ice

I came across the following question here: *[Is there a safe way to de-ice an unsealed driveway?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/is-there-a-safe-way-to-de-ice-an-unsealed-driveway)*  The accepted answer mentions rock salt being fine for such a driveway (asphalt), and the other answer mentions sand as an one alternative.

Whereas: What to do for a a **patterned concrete walkway** (or driveway)?  We've heard from a number of sources that regular de-icing salt / rock salt is **not** safe and will probably cause the concrete to deteriorate over time.

So, ruling out traditional de-icing salt and sand too (we don't find it very effective), what *other* products are there to de-ice a concrete walkway?

If possible, please describe the chemicals being used in the products mentioned and not just the brand name. I'm also interested in favoring environmentally-friendly products.  Still, the most important thing is to do the job of melting the ice so the walkway is safe for walking on.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, Salt will eventually harm or "shell" concrete.  I would suggest potassium chloride. This product will de-ice down to apx 15 F and will not harm the concrete or adjoining lawns or other plantings. Potassium chloride comes in a variety of brand names and can be found at most hardware stores.  We use it all the time for roof de-icing because it will not harm roofing,siding and vegetation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that potassium chloride works better and is less harmful. It will also cost more. The best de-icer for concrete is magnesium chloride. It works down to -25 degrees F and is the least harmful to your concrete. It costs more as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Calcium chloride works best** for deicing (down to -25 °F) and it releases heat as it dissolves. So, using less means having fewer problems. In terms of usage rates, calcium chloride is less toxic or corrosive than sodium, potassium, or magnesium chloride.

- Sodium chloride only works down to +20 °F
- Potassium chloride only works down to +25 °F
- Magnesium chloride only works down to 0 °F

**Potassium chloride is not commonly used for deicing because it has relatively low melt volume capability.** And Magnesium chloride contains about 55% water, so you actually have to use about twice the amount of it!

But ALL chloride materials will have (pound for pound) about same level with corrosiveness... so the more you use, the more corrosion and toxicity you get.

**Calcium and/or magnesium acetate is essentially non corrosive** (it has about the same corrosiveness as tap water). Acetates (same ingredient as hand warmers) work okay for deicing (+20 °F is about the same as sodium chloride) but they aren't quite as effective as chlorides. The upshot is that **acetates are way less toxic than chlorides**. The biggest downside is the cost. So acetates are usually mixed with chlorides to offset costs.

**Urea** is also sometimes used, because (like calcium chloride) it also releases heat as it melts and it is lower in toxicity to plants and wildlife than chlorides. The downside is that it doesn't work as well (only down to +25 °F).

Also, cat litter (and/or sand or any other gritty) deserves an honorable mention. It's not the best in the world, but it can help by absorbing heat from the sun and adding some grit for stepping on (making the road less slippery). It's common road treatment in my area to mix sand and grit with salt.

And so with that in mind, a mixture would probably be in your best interest. I can't really advise you without knowing a little more about your weather conditions, but for example, I might recommend the following mixture:

1. 100 parts sand
2. 50 parts urea
3. 50 parts calcium/magnesium acetate
4. 50 parts cacium chloride

Also, as more of a footnote, carbon black has been used in experiments and found to work. The black color absorbs sun rays and warms the snow.

Cons: Of course it would only work during the day and the water would re-freeze at night; it will not work if it snows after treatment (snow covering the black); having black stuff everywhere; solar powered.

Pros: It does work (if it's applied to the top of snow); carbon black has no toxicity or corrosiveness; and a little bit will go a long way, so it is very cost effective; solar powered.